# Is the 1-simplex left homotopic to the 0-simplex?

Tags: simplicial-stuff

I know they are weak equivalent (as simplicial sets). Is there a proof that they are NOT left homotopic? Here 'left homotopy' means there is a map
$$f:\triangle[1]\times\triangle[1]\to\triangle[1]$$
such that
$$f(0,t)=id, f(1,t)=0\text{ or }1$$
.

Comment: What do you mean by "left homotopic"?

Comment: I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: There is such a map. Functor $\mathrm{Poset} \to \mathrm{Cat} \to \mathrm{sSet}$ preserves products and $\Delta[1]$ is the image of the poset $\{ 0 < 1 \}$. It is obvious that there is a monotone map with these properties.

Comment: Well, aren't there only finitely many such maps? Cannot one check them? And one can work in the category of 1-skeletal simplicial sets...

Comment: Sorry for baby question. @DavidRoberts

Comment: @NanjunYang no need to apologise! Please take this as encouragement that it's a tractable problem, and not at all as intimidating as it seems :-)